# Why different format method behave differently in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, formatting, format

I was learning Python as a beginner. Recently I learnt about formatting methods, dictionaries and etc. Currently I was studying for loop and discovered a functioned called enumerate (probably nothing to do with is problem). I was applying what I had learnt till now by mixing everything. Suddenly I discovered that two format method acts differently!! How and why is this happening? Please explain.

**Method 1:**

```
nameAgeDictionary = {'Jack': 38, 'John': 51, 'Alex': 13, 'Alvin': 'Not Available'}

for index, name in enumerate(nameAgeDictionary):
    print('(%d) Name = %s, Age = %s' % (index+1, name, nameAgeDictionary[name]))  # Format_Method_1
```

**Output:**

(1) Name = Jack, Age = 38

(2) Name = John, Age = 51

(3) Name = Alex, Age = 13

(4) Name = Alvin, Age = Not Available

**Method 2:**

```
nameAgeDictionary = {'Jack': 38, 'John': 51, 'Alex': 13, 'Alvin': 'Not Available'}

for index, name in enumerate(nameAgeDictionary):
    print('({0:d}) Name = {1:s}, Age = {2:s}'.format(index+1, name, nameAgeDictionary[name])) # Format_Method_2
```

**Output:**

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "PATH_to_File.py", line 3, in

print('({0:d}) Name = {1:s}, Age = {2:s}'.format(

ValueError: Unknown format code 's' for object of type 'int'

**I have tried putting d in the place of s, on that case, it prints first 3 lines and gets stucked in last line (e.g. Not Available).**

Comment: [2.4.3. Formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals). You can force the conversion to `str` with `!`. `print('({0:d}) Name = {1:s}, Age = {2!s}'.format(index+1, name, nameAgeDictionary[name]))`

Comment: Thank you! That is working! But as assumed in the answer by user_na, that in contrast to .format() the % formatting calls __str__ as a fallback. What's your opinion on that? I am asking this to you as well as user_na wasn't completely sure of the reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the type of the age is mixed (`str`and `int`), just don't specify the type.

```
for index, name in enumerate(nameAgeDictionary):
    print('({0:d}) Name = {1:s}, Age = {2}'.format(index+1, name, nameAgeDictionary[name])) # Format_Method_2
```

By doing this `__str__` of the input should be called which savely converts the `int` to `str`. The result is:

```
(1) Name = Jack, Age = 38
(2) Name = John, Age = 51
(3) Name = Alex, Age = 13
(4) Name = Alvin, Age = Not Available
```

I assume (but I am not completly sure) that in contrast to `.format()` the `%` formating calles `__str__` as fallback.

**Update**

Here is the proof that `%` formating is calling `__str__`:

```
class test():
     def __str__(self):
         return 'bar'
 
foo = test()
print('%s'%(foo))
```

prints

```
bar
```

Comment: Thank you! This is working totally fine! But I still don't understand this thing: Why is in method 1 it is still working even after specifying the type as a string? (e.g. with %s)?
Why is method 1 not showing the error that Method 2 was giving me?

Comment: As I said, I assume that the first one calls `__str__` in case the input is not a string as specified in the input, while the second one does not handle the error.

Comment: Oh! Accha, now I am starting to understand what might cause this behavior difference to happen. Thank you so much @user_na for elaborating this repeatedly  :-)

Comment: Wow, great! Thank you so much for your help @user_na, without your help it would have remained as a confusion to me forever.